# How to Request Direct Sponsored Content Poster Role in Linkedin API?

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I am getting a 404 Error when I try to make the `GET` request to make a member a Direct Sponsored Content Poster Role on an Organization.

So following the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control#request-direct-sponsored-content-poster-role), I am using the organization ID and I am using the person that I want to add ID to the URL request. So my code looks like this:

```
    sendRequest(GET, "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationAcls/" + URLEncoder.encode("(organization:urn:li:organization:" + organization + ",role:DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER,roleAssignee:urn:li:person:" + roleAssignee +")" , StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()), null);
```

With the `sendRequest` method:

```
    public String sendRequest(String method, String url, String parameters) throws ExternalApiException, IOException{
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // add request header
    con.setRequestMethod(method);
    
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    if (method == POST) 
        //Removed POST logic as its irrelevant
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Lastly, an example of the URL post-encodement is as follows, with `organization = 1234567` AND `roleAssignee = abcDEfg`:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationAcls/%28organization%3Aurn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A1234567%2Crole%3ADIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER%2CroleAssignee%3Aurn%3Ali%3Aperson%3AabcDEfg%29`

Update 1 (11/10/2020): Wanted to add the response body that was returned as well. As mentioned the error code is `404` and the response body returned was:

```
{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Resource organizationAcls does not exist","status":404}
```

Comment: The docs is not really clear: seems strange a `GET` verb then talk about a `Request Body Fields`

Comment: I know. I tried to add the `request body` to the `GET` request yet I still get a 404 error. Although this is very uncommon.

Comment: I've tried using `POST` also without any success...

Comment: Hi! Have you solved?

Comment: No, but I have found that Linkedin provides a [LinkedIn Developer Support Portal](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us), which is basically a ticket system to help developers with technical issues they may be facing. I had to reach out to LinkedIn in order to find the site as it is not listed anywhere on the developer docs. But, I will update the post with any important information that can help you and other users.

Comment: cool! Thanks for let us know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spoke with a Linkedin Technical Support member and it appears there is an error in their documentation.

The correct call requires a `PUT` request.

Additionally, the URL for the request is: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationAcls/(organization:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXXX,role:DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER,roleAssignee:urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3AXXXXXXX).
Where the 'XXXXXXX' needs to be the associated organization id and the associated person id.

Lastly, as part of the request, a request body needs to be passed in. The request body is a `JsonObject` that contains the following properties.

1. `state`
2. `role`
3. `roleAssignee`
4. `organization`

For `state`, the only possible value is `REQUESTED`.
For `role`, the only possible value is `DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER`.
For `role assignee`,  it is `"urn:li:person:" + roleAssignee`, the id of the user you wish to use add to the below organization.
Lastly, for the `organization`, it is `"urn:li:organization:" + organization`, the id of organization you wish to add the above user to.